# Angular open a link always in a new tab Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, hyperlink

I have the following Angular code to download a PDF document. It works fine in other browsers but in Firefox when browser settings are set to "Open in Firefox" for PDF download then it doesn't open a new tab.

```
const blob = new Blob([data], { type: docType });
const blobDoc = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = blobDoc;
link.download = 'Filename.pdf';
link.click();
```

What I want is that in case of Firefox the link must always be open in a new tab. Even if when I set the target attribute, it doesn't open the new tab.

```
link.target = '_blank'
```

I tried the following and it works but then I do not get the file name.

```
const agent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (agent.indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
  window.open(blobDoc, '_target');
 } else {
  // Normal download
}
```

Comment: The above code works fine in all browsers but in Firefox it opens the download inside the same tab and I need it to open in a new tab regardless of Firefox settings.

Comment: window.open(blobDoc, '_target'); will open it in a new tab even if you set Firefox DO NOT OPEN PDF in a Tab.

Comment: This behaviour is a new bug/feature ( choose the best ) started with Firefox 98. According to the [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1758962), its fixed in Firefox 101.